# Intermittent subscript out of range error indicating open workbook is not open

Tags: excel, vba

I am randomly getting a subscript out of range error. However, when I restart my machine sometimes the script runs successfully.

I have Excel exports(XLS) that are delivered to Outlook in a Zip file. There are three files I open. The VBA script lives in a workbook I use to import those files.
When the files are open along with the workbook that houses the script, sometimes I run into a subscript error when I run the macro to import.

The indented line below is where the error gets thrown.

```vb
Sub Update()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("CCDR Source").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Handle Times Source").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Agent Detail Report-Source").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("CCDR Source").Select

Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops CCDR.xls").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:R")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops Workbook v3.2.0.xlsm").Worksheets(6).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn


    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops Handle Times.xls").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:W")

Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops Workbook v3.2.0.xlsm").Worksheets(7).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops Active Agents.xls").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:O")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Daily Ops Workbook v3.2.0.xlsm").Worksheets(8).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn*emphasized text*

Sheets("ACD Service Levels Pivot").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Daily Ops ACD Stats").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Update Complete", vbOKOnly
```

Comment: `The indented line below is where the error gets thrown` - the only way it can throw that error is when there is no workbook `"Daily Ops Handle Times.xls"` currently opened.

Comment: @Gserg the workbook "Daily Ops Handle Times.xls" is open along with the other two exports needed to import into workbook "Daily Ops Workbook v3.2.0.xlsm". The workbook comes from a zip file( and is not saved anywhere). Is VBA not recognizing the open workbook type?

Comment: When it happens next time, examine the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: It's possible the "missing" file is open in a different instance of excel from where your code is running

Comment: @TimWilliams I never thought of that. Is there a special script that has to be written to always look for that instance? How would I go about checking the instance?